# is there a "local-file-path aware text editor" exists?

Tags: linux, plugins, editor, configuration-files

**What is `local-file-path aware text editor`?**
I say `local-file-path aware text editor`, i mean a text editor with this feature: it can recognize local file pathes in text file, and

1. can open corresponding files when click on those pathes.
2. open all corresponding files by click some button like `open all included files`.

This is similar with `<a>` in html.

Wildcard in path should be supported, for examples:

```
/home/XXX/test.txt
../test.txt
./*.text
```

**Why i need this feature?**
In linux, most configuration files is modularized, which means a main configure file includes many   modularized configuration files, like nginx, apache.

With this feature, and another feature `search all in buffer` will turn a regular text edior into a handy configuration-file editor.

**My question:**

1. Is there any editor with this feature?  if not,
2. Is there any editor provides extensions what i can write a plugin for
   this?

What do you think?

Comment: I don't see how [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor) can fail you here as long as you don't have to literally "click" on the link, although they probably have a plugin for that too.

Comment: @shakabra  I am just a basic vim user, does vim recognize path like `./*.text` and can open them all by just one command?

Comment: I don't think it work exactly that way and there is a steep learning curve. But you can open a file easily with `:e` and use tab completion while looking for the file. Vim isn't for everyone, but it _can be_ super efficient. [Check out this page for common shortcuts](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html).

Comment: @shakabra I don't think this is local-file-path aware, vim doesn't know any path in your text file, and just open files you feed it. anyway this command is handy! ^_^

Comment: Well I guess I don't understand the term "local file path aware" because VIM can open up a complete file-manager to let me view/select all of my files in a tree. How does it do this without being aware of the file path?

Comment: @shakabra `local file path aware`, i mean editor can know what files to open just based on opened files, and you don't need to tell them. like many editors is `http://` url aware, they know `http://` url, and when you click on it, they can open it in browser, you don't need to type the url yourself, right?